# command 'vagrant box add' fail

Tags: vagrant

[vagrantup.com](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/boxes.html) says input `vagrant box add hashicorp/precise32`, 
But when I input it, the terminal outputs error message:

```
This command was not invoked properly. The help for this command is
available below.

Usage: vagrant box add <name> <url> [--provider provider] [-h]
```

Then, I input `vagrant box add hashicorp/precise32 \ http://files.vagrantup.com/hashicorp/precise32.box`, 
But the download fail, with following error message.

```
Download failed. Will try another box URL if there is one.
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

Couldn't open file /Users/XXXX/ http:/files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box
```

How do I do to install vagrant box?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The syntax for the `vagrant box add` subcommand is changed with the version 1.5, due to the [Vagrant Cloud](https://vagrantcloud.com/) introduction.

From the output messages it seems that you're using an older version, so current documentation is not reliable for your case.

[Here](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/4f0eb9504cc786d5a57a43814427e8eb35407a4c/website/docs/source/v2/cli/box.html.md) you can find a snapshot of the old documentation, in any case the syntax you need to use is like the following:

```
vagrant box add precise32 http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, had me stuck for a while. In the end I updated my version of vagrant which fixed it http://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html

Comment: I just tried this and got a 404 for your URL. `http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box` worked for me, though.

Comment: Alex, according to the [docs](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/boxes.html), "`vagrant box add`...stores the box under a specific name so that multiple Vagrant environments can re-use it." In version 1.0 these were downloaded to `~/.vagrant.d/boxes`. Not sure if this is the same in v2, but the basic idea is not to store base boxes in your project directory, but in a consistent place outside your project where Vagrant knows to look.